# Remove Last Characters from my filenames in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, filenames, rename

Im quite new to batch programming and i wanted to remove the last characters on my filename.

```
10_myfile_12345_6789.txt
11_myfile_12345_0987.txt
```

I want to remove the last 4 digits on my filename how i could do that?

I have tried this

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set X=3
set FOLDER_PATH=
pushd %FOLDER_PATH%
for %%f in (*) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    ren "%%f" "!filename!%%~xf"
)
popd
PAUSE
```

but it removes on first and last characters, i only saw this here too, im still quite confused how this works

Comment: what language. what have you tried?

Comment: I've edited my post, i'm runnong it on dos

Comment: @XanderVane Are you trying to remove the file extension? Or are you trying to remove the four characters before the file extension? For example - Should `10_myfile_12345_6789.txt` become `10_myfile_12345_6789`, or `10_myfile_12345_.txt`?

Comment: @unclemeat im trying to remove the four characters before the file extension

Comment: There are many utilities, like RenameMaster, that can do this. Why can you not use one of them?

Comment: im not allowed to install anything in my laptop even if its freeware cause of security risk

Comment: That RenameMaster was awesome!  It removed the last character from the file name of 630 files, saving me tons of time.  I didn't even need to install anything.  It's just a ZIP file with an executable that runs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With your recent clarification - I would do the following.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set FOLDER_PATH=C:\Some\Path\
for %%f in (%FOLDER_PATH%*) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    ren "%%f" "!filename:~0,-4!%%~xf"
)
PAUSE
```

This will change your examples

```
10_myfile_12345_6789.txt
11_myfile_12345_0987.txt
```

Into

```
10_myfile_12345_.txt
11_myfile_12345_.txt
```

If you want to remove the trailing `_` simply change `!filename:~0,-4!` to `!filename:~0,-5!`. This is simple [string manipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php).

Comment: thanks for this, but it seems that the directory name was changed

Comment: @XanderVane I didn't actually test my solution - My bad. See the updated version. Added `*` in the for loop to get contents of directory, instead of the directory itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
::working script to rename + remove suffix
::fixed problem file is not found while rename.
@echo off
set /a count = 0
for %%i in ("*.ts") do (set fname=%%i) & call :rename
goto :eof
:rename
::template name ==>   names__1xxx.ts
::to rename the begin  change zero to something
set name=%fname:~0,-8%
set /a count=count+1
::by random or count i bypass the problem of file not found while rename
ren "%fname%" "%name%_%count%.ts`
```

Results :

before : names__1xxx.ts

after  : names__1.ts

Answer (score 0):

Thank you SO much to DIMM_V2; the file is now as follows:

```
::working script to rename + remove suffix
::fixed problem file is not found while rename.
@echo off
set /a count = 0
for %%i in ("*_removed.PDF") do (set fname=%%i) & call :rename
goto :eof
:rename
::template name ==> name_removed.PDF
::to rename the begin  change zero to something
set name=%fname:~0,-12%
set /a count=count+1
::by random or count i bypass the problem of file not found while rename
ren "%fname%" "%name%.PDF"
```

This worked PERFECTLY.  The file gets renamed just as I wanted.  It was pretty simple to just highlight the file, press F2, and rename it - but it was a pain in the butt, as I'm having to do this fairly frequently.  This batch file has made my life much, MUCH easier!  Thanks again!