# Batch file to copy files from 1 day before and no more

Tags: windows, batch-file

imagine that I have 2 folders:

- **C:\FolderData** (will be incremented daily with new files)
- **C:\FolderTemp** (Needs to have only files from the day before executing, excluding hours/timestamp)

The **FolderData** will receive filenames that if not for date would be equals, as in:

1. SYS_PURCHASES_20170612.xls
2. SYS_PURCHASES_20170613.xls
3. SYS_PURCHASES_20170614.xls

If I run the .bat file **today** I need that **only** the *SYS_PURCHASES_20170613.xls* be copied over to **FolderTemp**.

I tried using `robocopy` but apparently **it can't receive the same value for minage and maxage**

`robocopy "C:\FolderData" "C:\FolderTemp" /minage:1 /maxage:1`

Also, if I try:

`robocopy "C:\FolderData" "C:\FolderTemp" /minage:1 /maxage:2`

It will bring **both** *SYS_PURCHASES_20170612.xls* and *SYS_PURCHASES_20170613.xls*, which is **not what I need**.

Other than that, I tried using `forfiles` but also with no avail.

`forfiles /p C:\FolderData /D -1 /C "/C /copy /y @file C:\FolderTemp"`

or even

`forfiles /p C:\FolderData /D -1 /C "/C /copy /y C:\FolderData\@file C:\FolderTemp"`

And other variables but it returns something along the line "the system can't return the specified file" times the number of files in the folder.

Note that there are **other processes involved bellow that should be ignored**, It's just that I can't figure out how to do **the step above**.

All steps my batch filed needs to do:

1. Copy from folder1 files from 1 day prior to folder2 (**what I need help**)
2. Remove last 9 digits from all files from folder2 (will remove the date, used the loop on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27932198/2970272)) so the file will be SYS_PURCHASES.xls
3. Move and replacing the files from folder2 to folder3 (using a simple `move /y`)

Comment: It's `/maxage:1`, not `/maxage1`; but you need `/maxage:2`, I guess. `forfiles` cannot work, because `/D -1` says to take files one day old or older (or, correctly spoken, last modified yesterday or eralier).

Comment: There is actually a work-around using `forfiles` -- see this post: [FORFILES date -after- (date calc in cmd file)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36585535)

Comment: @aschipfl the `maxage1` and `maxage1` was a typo on my Question, will fix it and then read the post you sent, ty.

Comment: Alright. `robocopy` also regards the time, so a file is considered a day old when it has been created/modified yesterday at the same time. `forfiles` however does not care about the time, so a file is considered a day old when it has been created/modified yesterday.

Comment: That was waaaaaaay advanced for me to understand where do I add the copy command inside the forfiles's inside loop, could you elaborate where the copy and folders would need to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to touch the files from yesterday only, I would use [`forfiles`](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html), because this command only regards the date but not the time, when specifying the `/D` option. [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) instead also regards the time, which is probably not what you want.

This is a possible way:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=C:\FolderData"
set "_TARGET=C:\FolderTemp"
set "_MASK=?*_????????.*"
set /A "_DAYS_AGO=1"

rem // Check given age and calculate interim value `PREV` needed for `forfiles`:
(if %_DAYS_AGO% LSS 0 set "_DAYS_AGO=0") & set /A "PREV=_DAYS_AGO+1"
rem // Let `forfiles` output the filtered files and capture them by `for /F`:
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
    rem/ Use two nested `forfiles` loops to filter for files of specified day: ^
        ^& forfiles /P "%_SOURCE%" /M "%_MASK%" /D -%_DAYS_AGO% ^
        /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE > nul 2>&1 forfiles /M @file /D -%PREV% || echo @file"
') do (
    rem // Store current file name and extension:
    set "FILE=%%~nF" & set "FEXT=%%~xF"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Copy the file and remove the last 9 characters from its name:
    > nul copy /Y "!_SOURCE!\!FILE!!FEXT!" "!_TARGET!\!FILE:~,-9!!FEXT!"
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm still checking the script. Is there a way to ignore file extensions? Because there will be .xls, .xlsx and .txt files in the Folder.

Comment: Sure; the variable (constant) `_MASK` defines the pattern to match, so just change the appropriate line: `set "_MASK=?*_????????.*"`

Comment: It didn't work :/ Does it uses date created or modified? Also tried changing the days ago from 0 to 10 (which are the dates I modified the files in the folder) and nothing... Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake concerning redirection -- see my edit. `forfiles` (as well as `robocopy`) regards the last modification date...

Comment: Hey, that did It! You made all the steps even thou I only needed just the one to move, thanks a bunch, I'll mark it as the answer. Now I need to check if I can pass the source and target folder as parameters!

Comment: Got it, changed the constants to  `set "_SOURCE=%1"` and `set "_TARGET=%2"`. Then I executed the bat file as cmd `> copy.bat c:\FolderData c:\FolderTemp`

Comment: You're welcome! You should write `%~1` and `%~2` instead to avoid trouble with quoted arguments. And you should not name a batch file like a command (`copy`) in order to avoid confusion...

Comment: I will... But I just got a new specification that I wasn't considering and I won't be able to use the solution you provided... Now I need to get the files where the date in the FILENAME equals 2 days prior... Since it's completely new thing, I'll create another question, cheers!