# Command line to remove and add characters from filename - Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

Thanks to this post: [Remove Last Characters from my filenames in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931611/remove-last-characters-from-my-filenames-in-windows/27932198)

I have been able to partially achieve my goal of removing the last two digits of the filenames in a directory, but I need to apply it to only .log files as other files live in that folder.

I have tried adding the .log part in a number of places, but it hasn't worked.

This script works in as much as it removes the last two characters from the filename correctly, but I need it to only perform it on .log extensions

Any help would be appreciated.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set FOLDER_PATH=C:\inetput\wwwroot\logs\
for %%f in (%FOLDER_PATH%*) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    ren "%%f" "!filename:~0,-2!00%%~xf"
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: `for %f in (c:\windows\*.log) do echo %f`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135

Comment: Simple, just add `.log` after your asterisk.. `for %%f in (%FOLDER_PATH%*.log) do`

Comment: Thank you both, I will try that.

Comment: As you're using `(C:\inetput\wwwroot\logs\*)`, `%%f` will be returned to include that path, therefore you may wish to use `If /I Not "%%~nxf"=="%~nx0"` instead of `if %%f neq %~nx0`.